# WalletConnect mobile application freezing

Tags: metamask, walletconnect

Good evening,
I tried to use #WalletConnect on my Android phone but once I started logging in and attempted to link my MetaMask to WalletConnect it transferred my funds to WalletConnect and now I have no access to do anything with the WalletConnect app because it has frozen at the screen below. Why does it want me to convert my funds? Why did it move the funds in the first place?

[image: Screen shot of WalletConnect]

Comment: The screenshot is missing. AFAIK WalletConnect doesn't have an official wallet, they recommend a series of wallet that support the protocol https://registry.walletconnect.org/wallets.

Comment: The screen shot is at the website listed at the bottom of the post.

Comment: The screenshot wasn't showing correctly, it should be fixed now. It shouldn't have transferred the tokens. Did you try contacting the wallet developers?

Comment: Yes I did. They do not have a support team. They told me to resolve it with MetaMask.  The only reason I even tried to use WalletConnect was so I could try to keep track of my nodes through the app.strongblock.com website on my mobile phone. As on mobile it won't link up through MetaMask for some reason and I seen WalletConnect was another option.

Comment: Are the funds available in metamask? Which wallet did you use? Did you enter the seed phrase in the wallet? I've used wallet connect with TrustWallet and Coinomi without issues.

Comment: No the funds are not available at all. I used MetaMask as my wallet. I did enter my seed phrase/secret recovery phrase into the app. It was either that or my private key to link the accounts.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems you have given your private key to a scamwallet. Never run an unknown application with an account that has important funds, only use wallets from reputable and well known teams, app stores verify apps shallowly and it is quite common they allow scamwallets.

Comment: I downloaded the app from the Google play store with the same icon displayed from the app.strongblock.com website. It seemed legit and reputable.  It's functions never indicated that it would import my funds from MetaMask  just link the two. Maybe app.strongblock.com should reconsider having the link on their site and the Google play store should remove and block applications from this company.

Comment: I don't see a direct link from strongblock to a store app. I've used walletconnect (the protocol) with trustwallet (as the wallet) and no issues so far. Many apps on the store are deceiving they copy logos and icons from another app/brand, check the developer and votes. Never trust an app with an unrelated developer, few votes, or low score.

Comment: If you try to access app.strongblock.com from a mobile phone it gives you 2 options for a wallet, either MetaMask or WalletConnect. I found MetaMask will not work in Google Chrome mobile app. So I tried the other option.

Comment: I tried the walletconnect app on the playstore, and it is a scamwallet. It is not an official wallet, if you read the reviews it was reported previously. I reported it. You have lost control of that address I suggest to create a new one.